# Aligning to right/left a LinearLayout inside a RelativeLayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a LinearLayout inside a RelativeLayout, and I want to align it to right or left depending of a value (it is a simple chat, left is own, right is the person who I am talking to), this is the layout code:

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_chat_message"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/chat_margin_default"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/chat_margin_default"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@drawable/textview_rounded_corners_receiver"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview_chat_message_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textIsSelectable="true"
                    android:autoLink="all"
                    android:text="Se"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview_chat_message_date_info"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                    android:text="10:32"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/chat_message_text_font_size"/>

            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see the `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` property is set.

The problem is, when I try to get access to the LayoutParams to set them to right or left, programmatically, it throws a casting exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
```

This is how I access the LayoutParams:

```
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.mChatMessageContainer.getLayoutParams();
            params.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
```

Where mChatMessageContainer is:

```
        mChatMessageContainer = (View) v.findViewById(R.id.layout_chat_message);
```

Lately there weren't any linearLayout inside the relative one and the code was working fine (I used a TextView instead of the LinearLayout), but I do need one now.

Reading the doc, I supposed I was accessing the parent layout params, that's why I cast it to relative, because if I change to Linear I have the same exception.

How can I set the alignment to THAT linearLayout programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

In LayoutParams  use parent view  LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout.

use

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.mChatMessageContainer.getLayoutParams();
```

instead of

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.mChatMessageContainer.getLayoutParams();
```

Comment: But ´LinearLayout.LayoutParams´does not have an addRule to add the ´RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT´property I need. And of course I cannot add a property of a Relative Layout.

Comment: then change your parent view as RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
          params.setMargins(50,0,0,0);
          params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
          holder.comment_layout.setLayoutParams(params);
          holder.comment_layout.setPadding(dipToPixels(mContext, 5), dipToPixels(mContext, 5), dipToPixels(mContext, 18), dipToPixels(mContext, 5));
```

dipToPixels Method:

```
public static int dipToPixels(Context context, float dipValue) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int px =(int) Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dipValue, metrics));

        return  px;
    }
```

Comment: It throws an exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams

Comment: If your parent layout is Relative then use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout.I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT //or left ,depends your value);
    holder.mChatMessageContainer.getChildAt(0).setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
```